# prevent itertools.islice from modifying lines

Tags: python

When reading a file line by line and if a string is found it will print a number of lines before & after. However when I grab the lines after, it removes them. How can I do this so the lines read are not affected

```
data.txt
----------------------------
apple
banana
carrot
dog
egg
food
george
hat
ink
jacket
kiwi
lemon
mango
```

---

```
import itertools
import collections

with open("text", "r") as f:
    linesBefore = collections.deque(maxlen=4)
    for line in f:
        line.rstrip()
        if "george" in line:
            history = list(map(str.strip, linesBefore))
            history.append(line.rstrip())
            append = list(itertools.islice(f, 4))
            append = list(map(str.strip, append))
        linesBefore.append(line)
        print(line.rstrip())
#print('\n'.join(history))
#print('\n'.join(append))
```

As you can see when printing the lines you can see the text grabbed after the string 'george' is not in the output

```
apple
banana
carrot
dog
egg
food
george
lemon
mango
```

Comment: Please explain "there" -- when it grabs the text, from where do the lines disappear?

Comment: @prune The four lines after `george` are not in the output as you can see

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are not in the output because you never printed them.  Your `if "george"` clause removes them from the file iterator and places them into `linesBefore`.  If you expect them to appear in the output, you must explicitly put them there.

I added a simple line to your clause:

```
    if "george" in line:
        history = list(map(str.strip, linesBefore))
        history.append(line.rstrip())
        append = list(itertools.islice(f, 4))
        append = list(map(str.strip, append))
        print(append)
```

The output is then

```
apple
banana
carrot
dog
egg
food
['hat', 'ink', 'jacket', 'kiwi']
george
lemon
mango
```

There are the missing words, right where you left them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by saving and restoring the current position of the file when the target line is seen — however you can't iterate through the file using `next()` (directly or indirectly via `for line in file:` or `itertools.islice()`) when using `seek()`, so you have to read the lines differently. Which is actually pretty simple to do:

```
import collections

with open("data_text.txt", "r") as f:
    linesBefore = collections.deque(maxlen=4)

    while True:
        line = f.readline().rstrip()
        if not line:
            break

        if "george" in line:
            posn = f.tell()  # Save where next line starts.
            history = list(map(str.strip, linesBefore))
            history.append(line.rstrip())
            append = [f.readline() for _ in range(4)]
            append = list(map(str.strip, append))
            f.seek(posn)  # Retore file position to where following line began.

        linesBefore.append(line)
        print(line.rstrip())
```

If you're using Python 3.8+, you can simplify the loop slightly by using the ["walrus" assignment operator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) that was added in that version.

```
import collections

with open("data_text.txt", "r") as f:
    linesBefore = collections.deque(maxlen=4)

    while (line := f.readline().rstrip()):
        if "george" in line:
            posn = f.tell()  # Save where next line starts.
            history = list(map(str.strip, linesBefore))
            history.append(line.rstrip())
            append = [f.readline() for _ in range(4)]
            append = list(map(str.strip, append))
            f.seek(posn)  # Retore file position to where following line began.

        linesBefore.append(line)
        print(line.rstrip())
```